# Spring Cloud Data Flow Authorization only configuration

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

We have a requirement where we need to enable only Authorization in Spring Cloud Dataflow server. The authetication will be done from an internal tool. Have tried with the authorization configuration alone leaving out the authentication configuration. But the endpoints are accessible even without an header with an authorization token. Please help with the configurations for enabling authorization only with SCDF server.

Dataflow Server Version: 2.3.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Data Flow support Oauth2/OIDC spec-compliant identity providers. Don't know what your "internal tool" is, and whether or not it is a compliant system.

Either way, you could use the [security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-security) from the ref. guide as to compare configuration options; we have a few samples in the [sandbox repo](https://github.com/jvalkeal/randomstuff/) (samples: uaa & keycloack), which you can use also as a reference.

Comment: Thanks Sabby, checked the documentation and examples. I am checking for a configuration where I can enable Authorization only not Authentication. The authentication will be done by external tool and a token will be generated. Using this token I will then hit the SCDF url which should validate my token and provide access to endpoints.

Comment: That is something like the below config only spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      security:
        authorization:
          provider-role-mappings:
            uaa:
              map-oauth-scopes: true
              role-mappings:
                ROLE_CREATE: foo.create
                ROLE_DEPLOY: foo.create
                ROLE_DESTROY: foo.create
                ROLE_MANAGE: foo.create
                ROLE_MODIFY: foo.create
                ROLE_SCHEDULE: foo.create
                ROLE_VIEW: foo.view

Comment: Without the below Authentication configuration
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          uaa:
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: dataflow
            client-secret: dataflow
            scope:                                                       
            - openid
        provider:
          uaa:
            jwk-set-uri: http://uaa:8080/uaa/token_keys
            ...